# Ionic title cannot be displayed in full

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

My ionic-title seems to be limited by my ionic-back-button [as can be seen here] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrfeL.png.

I cannot find a way to change this. I want the title to be lager than the button itself. Here is my HTML code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button text="" defaultHref="/" style='color:white'></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Upload
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

And my global.css

```
  ion-title {
    --color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:4vh;
    padding:0;}

  ion-toolbar{
    --background: #228B22;
    --min-height:16vh;
    padding:0;}
```